# Bootstrap - Background Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 3 column setup within a customer container container-home. The container home contains a semi-transparent white background which I am expecting to flow behind the subsequent icons.

However, the background appears just as a bar and doesn't flow behind the icons.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/qrvvwg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit : if you dont want to set a height for the container, you could follow this method as well where you set a background for the bootstrap columns instead of the container. I think this is more reliable as you dont need to be worried about whether you've set the height right http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrvGNa

The problem is that the contents of your container-home are bootsrap columns. So naturally they are floated to the left and taken out of the normal document flow. Therefore their container doesnt have a height. You'd have to set a height in order for the conatiner to have a background-color like so. check out my change --> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMGQmx

```
.container-home {
 height:165px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
 }
```

if you want the height to be responsive you can set it with vh like so

```
    .container-home {
 height:10vh; /*or whatever height you want*/
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
 }
```

Comment: Is this going to mobile responsive however, as the height of the columns varies depending on window size? I tried the VH and changing the window size breaks this

Comment: Yes vh is a resposive measurement. However, I just examined your code. The contents of your container-home all had fixed font-sizes if im not wrong? They're not dependent on the screen size so there would be no problem if you fixed the height in pixels.

Comment: Also i suggest you go through this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float . It will give you an idea of how float affects elements and why you faced the above issue.

Comment: Ok so using VH it covers the glyphicon and the first <p> but not the second <p>?

Comment: You have to increase the vh value until it covers all the elements you want.